# Is the symbol $e$ for the base of natural logarithm honoring Euler?

Tags: notation

According to Internet (actually, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) and [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/e.html)), I have two information:  It was Euler who first introduced the symbol $e$ (before people used $b$);  the symbol is to honor Euler.

I find this very strange.  My theory is that $e$ is for "exponential" not for Euler.

So what is the evidence that Euler was using the symbol to "honor" himself?

Comment: See [here](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/HistTopics/e.html) for details.

Comment: And see Leonhard Euler, [Introductio in analysin infinitorum](https://books.google.it/books?id=_zpRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA90) (1748), page 90, for the definition: "Ponamus. autem brevitatis gratia pro numero hoc $2,718281828459$ etc. constanter litteram $e$, quae ergo denotabit basin Logarithmorum naturalium seu hyperbolicorum, cui respondet litterae $k=1$ [in the previous defined infinite sum]".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the [The number e](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/history/HistTopics/e.html) page, one can find the following:

> As far as we know the first time the number e appears in its own right
>   is in 1690. In that year Leibniz wrote a letter to Huygens and in this
>   he used the notation b for what we now call e.  [...] Retrospectively,
>   the early developments on the logarithm became part of an
>   understanding of the number e.

Later:

> So much of our mathematical notation is due to Euler that it will come
>   as no surprise to find that the notation e for this number is due to
>   him. The claim which has sometimes been made, however, that Euler used
>   the letter e because it was the first letter of his name is
>   ridiculous. It is probably not even the case that the e comes from
>   "exponential", but it may have just be the next vowel after "a" and
>   Euler was already using the notation "a" in his work. Whatever the
>   reason, the notation e made its first appearance in a letter Euler
>   wrote to Goldbach in 1731

Some other details are given [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-origin-story-of-e-base-of-natural-exponential-function):

> Euler started to use the letter e for the constant in 1727 or 1728, in
>   an unpublished paper on explosive forces in cannons, and the first
>   appearance of e in a publication was Euler's Mechanica (1736). While
>   in the subsequent years some researchers used the letter c, e was more
>   common and eventually became the standard.

Answer (score 5):

You are right and your Internet source is wrong. First, Euler introduced this notation himself. And clearly this stood for "exponential". Euler was a modest person, and I cannot imagine him naming anything for himself. Second, if someone wanted to name something after Euler, s/he would choose capital E.

Comment: Someone needs to change the Wikipedia then ...

Comment: I don't think it's "clear" that $e$ stood for "exponential". Do you have any evidence for this claim?

Answer (score 2):

It was common among mathematicians of the 17th century to use vowels; thus Fermat's writing on adequality is full of A's and E's.  Since A is used much too often the choice of the next vowel, E, was all too natural. I don't think Euler used the symbol to honor himself. Possibly once he chose E, the symbol was retained by later mathematicians so as to honor Euler.